# How do you declare a type alias in a scala constructor?

Tags: class, scala, types, case, abstract

If I have a class that takes a tuple in its constructor among other values such as:

```
class Foo(a: Int, b: String, c: (Int, String))
```

How do I use an abstract type to give the tuple a more descriptive name in a lightweight fashion (without wrapping it in a new class):

```
class Foo(a: Int, b: String, c: Dave)
```

I'm not sure how to bring a type alias in scope (or if this is the best thing to do):

```
type Dave = (Int, String)
```

Is there a convention for where to define types in this way (or should I be defining case classes and wrapping everything...)?

I appreciate that it does not make sense in a lot of situations but if I'm really only looking for a more descriptive name is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400734/package-objects)

Comment: 'type aliases' is a far better term than I managed to come up with...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a type alias like:

```
scala> type MyTuple = Tuple2[Int,String]
defined type alias MyTuple

scala> val x = new MyTuple(1, "one")
x: (Int, String) = (1,one)
```

Comment: Yes it was the scoping of the type alias that I was having trouble with, Jamil pointed me to package objects in the comment above.

Comment: @MatthewPickering please close question