# Scala: How to always make certain utils available to sub packages?

Tags: scala, import, package, implicit-conversion, predef

All my code is under `package com.company.project`. In almost all of my files, I end up importing some common things like `import scala.util.{Failure, Try, Success}` and `import scala.util.control.NonFatal` etc. Is it possible to somehow setup a package object in such a way that all these utils are always available to all sub packages in `com.company.project.sub` (kind of my own project level [Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$))?

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a [package object with type aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400734/package-objects):

```
package com.company.project

import scala.util

package object sub {
  type Failure = util.Failure
  type Try = util.Try
  type Success = util.Success
  type NonFatal = util.control.NonFatal
}
```

Comment: But, I have many different `sub` e.g. `com.company.project.foo` and `com.company.project.bar` etc and I want these utils to be available for all **sub** packages of `com.company.project.*.*.*...`

Comment: No way there without importing `com.company.project.sub._` - but that does limit the boilerplate to one line.