# Is it possible in Scala to have functions/methods inside a package{}?

Tags: scala, zio

I am currently following Miss Wiem Zine's article (specifically on ZIO): [Make your program testable](https://medium.com/@wiemzin/make-your-program-testable-cee543c6fbbf)

but I couldn't get pass the

```
package console {
  def println(line: String): ZIO[Console, Nothing, Unit] =
    ZIO.accessM(_.console println line)

  val readLine: ZIO[Console, Nothing, String] = 
    ZIO.accessM(_.console.readLine)
}
```

I've read in [alvin alexander's page](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-control-scala-method-scope-object-private-package), but it's all about scoping.

[I tried it in intellij, but it complains.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvg2B.png)

Could it be a

```scala
package object console {
...
}
```

instead of `package console {}`?

Or is that a scala 3 thing? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think it is a Scala 3 thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56566166/14955

Comment: the other examples use `package object` see for Example: https://github.com/jdegoes/functional-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/net/degoes/06-application/configuration/package.scala

Comment: @Thilo thanks for the link. I don't usually use it too, just only found out about it when I started studying zio.

Comment: @pme since you've mention it, I scourged articles from John De Goes and finally found it: http://degoes.net/articles/zio-environment

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala 2, we have a concept of package objects. There are examples here: https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html.

I think code snippet from "Wiem Zine's article" is missing `object` keyword, so you are right it should be: `package object console`, since the whole example is on ZIO and Scala 2.x. There is no ZIO for Scala 3 yet, as far as I know :-)

@Thilo is also right that Scala 3 allows us to use top-level definitions right in the file without necessity to wrap into a block. Until Scala 3, one can use `package object` to get common package code.